# mongod --datapath can't read collections from copied data folder from another pc

Tags: mongodb

My windows crashed so I copied the data folder of mongodb which I used to run `mongod --datapath "C:/data"` to another PC.

But when I run `mongod --datapath "C:/data"`, I can't see my old collections.

How can I make it ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same version of mongod and most important thing is the same storage engine (mmap or wiretiger) ?. Can you compare and post mongod.cnf ?

Comment: sure is wiretiger and I don't use mongod.cnf

Comment: Do you see anything in logs? What is the mongod and mongo shell version in both cases?

Comment: And sure the same version of mongod ? You don’t use mongod.cnf so it will use default config and it has some changes in each version( admin db, default storage engine ...). But if you the same version i have no idea about this problem, may be your file has problem with permission or crash, you should run console and check start up log too

Comment: One more thing, some old gui query tools doesn’t support wiretiger and using them you cannot show collections

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone. I remember that my dbpath is /data/db and the log path is /data/log. Not a /data for all. Thanks